# Undo Restore Previous versions

Tags: windows-server-2008, vss

I'm running windows server 2008.  I've restored a previous version using shadow copy, and then realised I didn't want to.  Is there any way to undo this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is not a newer "previous version", you will need to ask your system administrator to restore it from the backups.

Answer (score 1):

The Vista kernel (and therefore all kernels based on it) automatically makes shadow copies of all deleted files. That includes moved files since they are "deleted" from one place and moved to another.

Your original file should now have a shadow copy. Restart Shadow Explorer to refresh it.