# File restore after Windows SBS 2011 Shadow Copy

Tags: windows, windows-sbs-2011, vss, data-recovery

I recovered my drive D with a shadow copy of November 2011 by accident, now all my files all users at our company created are gone and there is no single external backup. Can I recover the files with some file recovery tool or is it gone forever?

Best,
Elmira

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to undo Shadow Copy restore you did by accident.
Please check if this post refers to your problem [Undo Restore Previous versions](https://serverfault.com/questions/291487/undo-restore-previous-versions)

Comment: When they've already said that they don't have a backup, referring them to another post where the accepted answer tells people to restore from backup seems less than helpful.

Comment: Rob, did you see the second answer there?It takes only few seconds to read through entire post.

Comment: Yes I did. I may turn out to be wrong in this but I'm giving the poster of *this* question enough credit to have already noticed if there were more suitable restore points prior to posting. In either case, if you wanted to point them at a specific answer instead of that question in general then you should use a more directed link, and ideally some context.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no other restore point which I could use, this would have been an easy fix. Here just everything went wrong: no external backup, no restore point, stupid me. I think the only thing left is file recovery.